# C++ UnixTimestamp and readable time format

Tags: c++, time, c++builder, ansistring

I get a timestamp as an AnsiString from my database in my C++ application.
It looks like this "2017-09-12 09:35:10".

Now I want to parse it back into an Unix Timestamp.

```
AnsiString myDate = Query->Fields->FieldByName("MyDates")->AsString;
TDateTime = StrToDateTime(myDate);
```

In my specific case I get the following date: *2017-08-10 08:43:35*

But the Unixtimestamp I get is: *42957.363599537*

Which is *01-01-1970 12:55:57* calculated back into readable format.

What am I missing here?!...

Comment: That looks like some kind of extended C++ (is `AsString` a member *variable* or some kind of "property" function?) And Unix timestamps are not floating point values, but integers so what you have is something different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if `FieldByName` returns a pointer to a struct, then `->AsString` could be a member variable... but I agree, that wouldn't be *expected*, but is *possible*.

Comment: @druckermanly Considering the types I suspect it's Embarcadero C++ builder, which might have added some extensions to the language. As well as not have "proper" Unix timestamps.

Comment: Why do you think `TDateTime` is a unix timestamp?

Comment: The application was built with Borland C++ 5.

Comment: I think it's a unix timestamp because the comments in the code say so.

Comment: `2017-09-12 09:35:10` is `1505208910` as a Unix timestamp. Nowhere even close to `42957.363599537`.

Answer (score 0):

You got **not** Unix TimeStamp, but [`TDateTime`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__TDateTime.html). The following is from Builder's documentation :

> The integral part of a TDateTime value is the number of days that have
>   passed since 12/30/1899. The fractional part of a TDateTime value is
>   the time of day.

In other case, the Unix TimeStump is a number of seconds from 01.01.1970

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Howard Hinnant's free, open source, header-only, date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) which extends the C++11 `<chrono>` header to handle calendrical computations.

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    std::istringstream in{"2017-08-10 08:43:35"};
    date::sys_seconds Unixtimestamp;
    in >> date::parse("%F %T", Unixtimestamp);
    std::cout << Unixtimestamp.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
    std::cout << date::format("%F %T\n", Unixtimestamp);
}
```

Output:

```
1502354615
2017-08-10 08:43:35
```

Comment: Nice, but the OP is using an old version of C++Builder that does not support C++11.

Comment: Too bad.  I am lucky to be able to work in modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

C++Builder 6 and later have a `DateTimeToUnix()` function in the `DateUtils` unit:

```
#include <SysUtils.hpp>
#include <DateUtils.hpp>

AnsiString myDateStr = Query->Fields->FieldByName("MyDates")->AsString;
TDateTime myDate = StrToDateTime(myDateStr);
__int64 myTimestamp = DateTimeToUnix(myDate);
```

If you are using C++Builder 5 or earlier, you can implement your own `DateTimeToUnix()` function like this:

```
#include <SysUtils.hpp>

// Days between TDateTime basis (12/31/1899) and Unix time_t basis (1/1/1970)
const __int64 UnixDateDelta = 25569;

__int64 DateTimeToMilliseconds(const TDateTime &ADateTime)
{
    TTimeStamp LTimeStamp = DateTimeToTimeStamp(ADateTime);
    return (__int64(LTimeStamp.Date) * MSecsPerDay) + LTimeStamp.Time;
}

__int64 DateTimeToUnix(const TDateTime &AValue)
{
    __int64 Result = abs(DateTimeToMilliseconds(UnixDateDelta) - DateTimeToMilliseconds(AValue)) / MSecsPerSec;
    if (AValue < UnixDateDelta)
        Result = -Result;
    return Result;
}
```

Also note that the version of `StrToDateTime()` you are using is subject to the user's current locale settings for date/time.  Since you are dealing with a very specific date/time format, I suggest you parse it manually and not rely on any particular locale, eg:

```
#include <SysUtils.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

AnsiString myDateStr = Query->Fields->FieldByName("MyDates")->AsString;

Word wYear, wMonth, wDay, wHour, wMin, wSec;
sscanf(myDateStr.c_str(), "%hu-%hu-%hu %hu:%hu:%hu", &wYear, &wMonth, &wDay, &wHour, &wMin, &wSec);

TDateTime myDate = EncodeDate(wYear, wMonth, wDay) + EncodeTime(wHour, wMin, wSec, 0);
__int64 myTimestamp = DateTimeToUnix(myDate);
```

If you are using C++Builder 2006 or later, you can use the overloaded version of `StrToDateTime()` that accepts a `TFormatSettings` struct as input:

```
#include <SysUtils.hpp>
#include <DateUtils.hpp>

String myDateStr = Query->Fields->FieldByName("MyDates")->AsString;

TFormatSettings myFmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
myFmt.ShortDateFormat = _D("yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss");
myFmt.DateSeparator = _D('-');
myFmt.TimeSeparator = _D(':');

TDateTime myDate = StrToDateTime(myDateStr, myFmt);
__int64 myTimestamp = DateTimeToUnix(myDate);
```